# How to refresh DataGrid in C# / WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, refresh

```
private void cmbEmployee_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string employee = (e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem).Content as string;

    dgFake.ItemsSource = newdal2.SelectUser(employee).Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

This method populates the data grid on my WPF windows form by a specific employee when this employee is clicked from a combo box, however, when I click another employee after the first, it doesn't refresh the data grid, but instead adds that employee's data beneath the first.

How do you refresh or delete the items in a Data Grid baring in mind this is on WPF Xaml Windows Forms, and it is not a DataGridView. I have tried these already and none have worked:

```
dgFake.Items.Refresh();
dgFake.Items.Remove(); //Required a remove item passed to the method, so too specific
dgFake.Itemssource = "";
```

Comment: Reload the datasource of your grid after the update !

Answer (score 3):

In general using WPF, we manipulate *data*, not *UI elements*. Therefore, after `Binding` a collection property to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property, we can simply work with the collection property:

In XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" ... />
```

Then in code:

```
YourCollection.Clear();
```

Or to change items:

```
YourCollection = someNewCollection;
```

> You will need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in order for the `DataGrid` to update automatically after changing the data like this.

---

UPDATE >>>

> In response to the comment: 'I have added the XAML code, when you talk about 'YourCollection' in the XAML code what needs to be put here?':

You'll need to create a `Bindable` collection property in your code; this can either be a `DependencyProperty` in your code behind, or a CLR property that implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). We generally don't display database elements in the UI, instead preferring to define object classes with the required properties:

```
public static DependencyProperty EmployeesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Employees", typeof(ObservableCollection<Employee>), typeof(YourUserControl));

public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Employee>)GetValue(EmployeesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EmployeesProperty, value); }
}
```

Then in your `cmbEmployee_SelectionChanged` handler method, you can update the collection property's value with something like this:

```
private void cmbEmployee_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
    string employee = (e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem).Content as string;
    foreach (DataRow row in newdal2.SelectUser(employee).Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        Employees.Add(new Employee(row.Id, row.Name, row.Whatever));
    }
    Employees = newdal2.SelectUser(employee).Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: I have added the XAML code, when you talk about 'YourCollection' in the XAML code what needs to be put here?

Comment: That sounds really techniqual for a beginner like me to understand :/ Thanks though.